# MongoDB Aggregation Framework - How To Query For An Average

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I rewrite this MongoDB query using the Aggregation Framework to return the average `price` for the following Model in between the supplied `date` range:

**Model**

```
var PriceSchema = new Schema({
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
};
```

**Query**

```
exports.getPriceAverage = function(req, res, next) {
    var start       = moment.utc('03-01-2012').startOf('day');
    var end         = moment.utc('03-01-2012').endOf('month')

    // Aggregation Framework Query Here...
    Price.find({ date: { $lt: end, $gt: start }}, function(err, priceAverage) {
         // Return average price...
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention using aggregation, but you're using the `find` function which would return all results to the client.

Instead, you need to use `aggregate` with [`$avg`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg):

```
Price.aggregate([
    { $match: { date: { $lt: end, $gt: start } } },
    { $group: { _id: null, avgPrice: { $avg: '$price' } } }

], function(err, results){
   // process the results (an array of JavaScript objects)
});
```